# main form resizing not showing the image buttons in child form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

I am working on a .NET C# application that has a main Form which is MDI container. When the user resizes the main form, scroll bars appear and the imagebuttons are covered by the scroll bars of the mainform...

When the form first loads the buttons are shown correctly.

Resizing the form(main form), the image buttons in child form become invisible (they are covered by main from scroll bars)

Would any one pls help on this for displaying images in child form ..

Many thanks

Comment: can you provide us with some sample images of what is correct and how it looks like after resizing. It is hard to imagine your problem without that. Or try to be more precise with your argumentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try merging the "image" buttons to the MDI Parent's `ToolStrip`.  You have to make the `ToolStrip` control on the child form invisible and set the `MergeAction` and `MergeIndex` properties in order to get it to work.  See [ToolStripManager.Merge Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5523fet0.aspx).

If you want them to stay on the child form, the scrollbars are going to come into play.  It's sort of the deal with MDI forms.

Comment: many Thanks for your support, I have implemented this method "ToolStripManager.Merge Method", its working fine...